# Modify some values in the weight file (.h5) of VGG-16

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I have the weight and bias values for each layer of the VGG model saved as a .h5 file. I got the file from: https://github.com/fchollet/deep-learning-models/releases/tag/v0.1

Now let's say I want to change a few values in that file. With help from [How to overwrite array inside h5 file using h5py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922584/how-to-overwrite-array-inside-h5-file-using-h5py), I am trying to do the same as follows:

```
import h5py
file_name = "vgg.h5"

f = h5py.File(file_name, 'r+')

# List all groups
print("Keys: %s" % f.keys())

# Get the data
data = (f['block2_conv1']['block2_conv1_W_1:0'])

print(data[0][0][0][0]) #prints some value, lets say X
data[0][0][0][0] = 0 #change it to zero
print(data[0][0][0][0]) #prints the same value X

f.close()
```

I get the same original value even after trying to assign something else to that index.

I am not sure how to change/modify the weight value and save it (in the same file or maybe a different one). Any help or suggestions on this will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
data[0,0,0,0]=0
```

ndarray objects need to update in this way rather than normal array-list.